# Umbraco MediaById not working as expected

Tags: razor, umbraco

Trying to display a set of images from uComponents' MNTP, and can't get a value for the umbracoFile property - in the example below, both umbracoFile and url return empty strings:

```
           foreach (var id in @Model.sliders) {
                var media = Model.MediaById(id.InnerText);
                if (media != null){
                    var url = media.umbracoFile;
                    <p>name = @media.Name</p>
                    <p>alt = @media.altText</p>
                    <p>url = @media.umbracoFile</p>
                    <p>url = @url</p>
                }
            }
```

It's getting really really really annoying... I've worked around it in other areas like so, using Model.Media:

```
<img src="@Model.Media("topRightImage", "umbracoFile")" alt="@Model.Media("topightImage", "altText")" />
```

But that will only help if with the media picker data type, not mntp. It shouldnt' be that difficult, should it?

I can get the images to load if I rebuild the internal search index, but they're gone again on subsequent refreshes.

I've seen others having similar problems, and would really appreciate a solution...

ta

Nathan

Comment: Do the other properties show up (name, altText etc), or are they empty as well?

Comment: Name and altText are both there, same with any other properties I've created. I've started using DAMP instead of the umbraco default picker, seems to work well - nice to have everything in the XML rather than having to query for it, and provides a better toolset for content creators. Still odd though as far as umbracoFile goes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug that was fixed in 4.7.2. See the following codeplex item:

http://umbraco.codeplex.com/workitem/30778

Comment: Isn't that only applicable for sites running the legacy schema? I'm using Examine to serve media - much quicker.

Comment: It's not clear in the referenced post if its only related to the schema, but it is listed as one of the issues. Have you tampered with the Examine settings at all? This post describes a similar issue after changing the Examine configuration: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/25859-DynamicNode-MediaById-umbracoFile-returning-empty-string